# Editing an old question to re-ask it without duplication: Naughty?

Tags: discussion, editing, exact-duplicates

I really want to get an answer to this question, even if in reality it's a No:

[Is it possible to create a calendar view with two entries per item?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7264/is-it-possible-to-create-a-custom-view-type)

Unfortunately this question has been marked as answered, when neither the answers nor the eventual solution are directly relevant; mostly because the OP's actual requirement is only indirectly related.

I would like to edit the question to be something closer to the OP's actual requirement ("How do I overlay two calendars on a view?" or similar), and then re-ask the question without fear of it being closed as a duplicate.

Is this acceptable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The title of a question should match its content. In this case, the title is broad and misleading (so please feel free to edit!).

The "exact duplicate" close reason means the questions must duplicate their meaning and intention (not just title).

Comment: Fair enough, thanks.